# Can I update a Zip file inside AWS S3 with powershell?

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3

I recently learned how to modify the contents of a Zip file with Powershell, in order to update it without having to recreate it completely, but now I have to do the same on AWS S3 with the Powershell module AWSToolsS3 and I I'm afraid it won't be possible.

My goal is to have two scripts. The first archives files on a file server and creates Zips for months and years.
This script is done and working.
The second script aims to copy the zips of months and years to an Amazon S3 Cloud.

However, there is a very small chance that a previously archived folder will be modified during a period when they are still accessible, and I therefore have to update any Zips that may have already been created.

These folders and Zips are very large and recreating them from scratch is not an option, so I have set up an optimized update system for Zips on the file server, and I would like to know if this is possible too with the AWSToolsS3 Powershell module

I can't seem to find in the Amazon documentation if it is possible to modify the contents of a Zip file without unzipping it.
So I ask the help of professionals from Powershell and AWS who will see my question.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "update it without having to recreate it completely" is a kind of illusion, the contents are probably reused but updating a zip-file in-place without just writing the whole thing with modifications to a temporary file is exceedingly difficult, I can't really imagine any library doing that. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. given the lack of answers, I guess you're right, and I suspected it a little, but I had to ask the question anyway. The script will only be run once a month, so this will limit the amount of information written to the Cloud S3.
Thank you for your comment.